# One Step Checkout Undefined index: country_id

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

I recently updated my Magento version to 1.9.3.8 and after that "**One step checkout**" not showing total cost with shipping price. I get an error in my system.log:

> Notice: Undefined index: country_id  in /public_html/app/code/local/MGS/Oscheckout/controllers/IndexController.php on line 258

Does anybody have a clue what's wrong? Thanks

```
  
    public function savebillingAction() { 
      $billing_data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
      $shipping_data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping', array()); 
      ..... 
      $billing = $quote->getBillingAddress(); 
      //line 258: 
      $billingCountryId = $billing_data['country_id'];
      $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($billingCountryId)->setCollectShippingRates(true);
      $billing->setCountryId($billingCountryId)->save(); 
      $shipping->setSameAsBilling(true)->save();
      ... 
    }
```

Comment: Is it this extension?  https://www.magesolution.com/magento-one-step-checkout.html

Comment: Yes, this is the same.

Comment: Can you post the function of that controller file that line 258 is referencing from the error?

Comment: <code>public function savebillingAction() { 
      $billing_data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
      $shipping_data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping', array()); 
      ...
      $billing = $quote->getBillingAddress(); 
      //line 258: 
      $billingCountryId = $billing_data['country_id'];
      $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($billingCountryId)->setCollectShippingRates(true);
      $billing->setCountryId($billingCountryId)->save(); 
      $shipping->setSameAsBilling(true)->save();
      ... 
    }</code>

Answer (score 0):

did you find a fix for this pelase I am stuck on same error but for different extension